# table with scrollable body and colgroup does not work

Tags: html, css

I want to define the width of the cols via colgroup. In addition the tbody shall be scrollable. But is does not work. I s there a solution without js?

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xuvsncr2/448/)

HTML

```
     <colgroup>
      <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
      <col span="1" style="width: 40%;">
      <col span="1" style="width: 20%;">
      <col span="1" style="width: 25%;">
    </colgroup>
```

Answer (score -1):

add to your css:

```
td:nth-child(1), th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 15%;
}
td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 40%;
}
td:nth-child(3), th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 20%;
}
td:nth-child(4), th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 25%;
}
```

tbody scrolling works fine in chrome. i dont know how it is in other browsers

Answer (score -1):

you need to set `display:inline-block;` to `<col>`

```
col{
  display: inline-block;
  height:20px;
  background: #000;
}
```

[**See demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/xuvsncr2/451/)