# Html table <colgroup> add scroll in table. Is it possible?

Tags: html, css, html-table, size

I have table with `<colgroup>` but I set up height UI Layout. Problem is that `<table>` completely ignore height, one way to fix it just setup for

```
 <tbody style='display:block; overflow-y:scroll'>
```

But it immediately broke column width. Whole table has size of first column.
How to combine this? Or may be another way to make such table scrollable.

Comment: can you show the exact problem with your code?

Comment: I belive something similar  described also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933403/table-with-scrollable-body-and-colgroup-does-not-work), but  cant even get descent scroll and set width as constant not option, table in dynamic UI layout.